sudo port install root6 failed
I am trying to install root6 using Macports packages on macOS Sonoma 14.4.1
At the very end of the installation an error occured and the installation has failed for installing root6.
Here is the error code in the main.log file:
:info:build make[1]: Leaving directory /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_science_root6/root6/work/build'
:info:build make: *** [all] Error 2
:info:build make: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_science_root6/root6/work/build'
:info:build Command failed:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_science_root6/root6/work/build" && /usr/bin/make -j12 -w all VERBOSE=ON  
:info:build Exit code: 2  
:error:build Failed to build root6: command execution failed 
:debug:build Error code: CHILDSTATUS 57087 2  
:debug:build Backtrace: command execution failed  
:debug:build     while executing  
:debug:build "system {*}$notty {*}$callback {*}$nice $fullcmdstring"  
:debug:build     invoked from within. 
:debug:build "command_exec -callback portprogress::target_progress_callback build". 
:debug:build     (procedure "portbuild::build_main" line 10). 
:debug:build     invoked from within. 
:debug:build "$procedure $targetname". 
:error:build See /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_science_root6/root6/main.log for details.

Is this a bug?

That ends with a tip to look in the main.log to see what was logged. Are you able to take that next step?

That looks like https://trac.macports.org/ticket/65779 .  The only successful build according to https://ports.macports.org/port/root6/details/ is ARM64 on Big Sur.  Been broken for a while.

Nice find @MarcWilson

Thanks a lot MarcWilson. It looks like I need to find a different way to install root6....
